# Is there a way to save OneNote file in Google Drive with Full sync

Tags: google-drive, onenote

I am using OneNote on a daily basis.  I save my one note normally to OneDrive to sync everything and access it from web and mobile.

Is there any way to save a file in Google Drive (have unlimited space) and perform a sync.

Example:

1. In OneNote > Click "New"
2. Select "Other web locations" > And select my Google Drive (any of the folders)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: could you add ways you took and failed for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "Full sync"? Have you already reviewed the Google Drive Help Center? Have you already uploaded a onenote file to Google Drive?

Comment: Is this about the desktop version of OneNote or on Office 365?

Comment: office 365 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- go to **[https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive?ths=true)** and drag-drop your OneNote file or
- download desktop app from **https://www.google.com/drive/download/**
- install it and make sure synchronization is enabled
- save your OneNote file to your Google Drive folder

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean drag-drop my OneNote File ? Does it mean it should be saved in my hard disk first and then drop it to google Drive? Which doesnt make any sense?

Comment: @RagavanRajan if you use the first link it will go straight to your Drive and every time you edit your OneNote file you need to "re-upload" it. if you use 2nd link you will install Drive app which will create a special folder on your hard disk and everything in that folder will be automatically synchronized with your Drive so all you need to do is to place your OneNote file into that folder and everytime you edit your file you just save your changes and all gets backed up.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the 2nd link approach. Whenever I created new OneNote file, It is creating new folder in my Google drive. But my actual problem is solved. It is syncing.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "full sync" because simultaneous edits by other users will create duplicate copies of the notebook, unlike syncing the notebook to OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

Install Google Drive app for desktop and select target folder where your OneNote files are ( which is generally in C:\users\public\documents ) and sync that folder. Your notes will automatically be synced with Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you've gotten an answer, but if you go press:

File
Share
Get a Sharing Link
Create a view link

Then, a viewable link that anyone can view is created.  There is also an option to create a link where anyone can edit the document.  Copy that link and share it!

Answer (score -2):

You just have to export your notebook or page as a onepack or onepage file and save it to your computer. Then just save your exported file to google drive